# How to convert java code in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

Here i have java code is looks like below:

```
this.mNetworkConnectionManager = new NetworkConnectionManager(new NetworkConnectionManager.OnNetworkListener() {

            @Override
            public void onNetworkPacketSent(String packet) {
                BASPacket bp = new BASPacket(packet);
                bp.setTimestampedPacket(timestampPacket(packet, "sent"));

                mOnBASMessageListener.onBASMessageSent(bp);
            }


        });
```

I try to convert these code in swift like below:

```
self.mNetworkConnectionManager = NetworkConnectionManager(l: { NetworkConnectionManager.OnNetworkListener() 
            func onNetworkPacketSent(packet : String)
            {
                var bp : BASPacket = BASPacket(packet: packet)
                bp.setTimestampedPacket(timestampPacket(packet, sentrec: "sent"));

                mOnBASMessageListener.onBASMessageSent(bp);
            }
        }())
```

But getting Compile error."Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11"

Also i have NetworkManager class like below in swift:

```
public class NetworkConnectionManager
{
    var mOnNetworkListener:OnNetworkListener = OnNetworkListener()

     init(l : OnNetworkListener)
    {
        self.mOnNetworkListener = l

    }
    class OnNetworkListener
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: The compiler should never crash, so that is a bug. But where do NetworkConnectionManager and the other used classes come from in your Swift code?

Comment: NetworkConnectionManager and the other used class are also swift class in app.If you know other way to convert above java code , than let me know.

Comment: Does it compile if you comment out whats inside onNetworkPacketSent function? I get this Segmentation fault: 11 whenever I try to access a local/method/instance variable inside a method inside these anonymous inner classes, or however you call them in Swift (that's what they're called in java). I think it's a compiler bug. Also read the logs more carefully around the segmentation error - it might tell you which declaration is causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Swift does not support anonymous class. If you ever want to override something in a class, you must create a subclass for it in swift.

```
public class NetworkConnectionManager
{
    var mOnNetworkListener:OnNetworkListener = OnNetworkListener()

    init(l : OnNetworkListener)
    {
        self.mOnNetworkListener = l

    }
    class OnNetworkListener
    {
        func onNetworkPacketSent(packet : String)
        {
            //default implementation
        }
    }
}

class MyOnNetworkListener : NetworkConnectionManager.OnNetworkListener
{
    override func onNetworkPacketSent(packet: String) {
        var bp : BASPacket = BASPacket(packet: packet)
        bp.setTimestampedPacket(timestampPacket(packet, sentrec: "sent"));

        mOnBASMessageListener.onBASMessageSent(bp);
    }
}

let mNetworkConnectionManager = MyOnNetworkListener()
```

If you don't have a default implementation, you can declare it as a protocol

```
public class NetworkConnectionManager
{
    var mOnNetworkListener:OnNetworkListener

    init(l : OnNetworkListener)
    {
        self.mOnNetworkListener = l
    }
}

protocol OnNetworkListener {
    func onNetworkPacketSent(packet : String)
}

class MyOnNetworkListener : OnNetworkListener
{
    func onNetworkPacketSent(packet: String) {
        var bp : BASPacket = BASPacket(packet: packet)
        bp.setTimestampedPacket(timestampPacket(packet, sentrec: "sent"));

        mOnBASMessageListener.onBASMessageSent(bp);
    }
}

let mNetworkConnectionManager = MyOnNetworkListener()
```

If the class/protocol consists of only one method, the better Swifty way is to pass a single closure.

```
public class NetworkConnectionManager
{
    var mOnNetworkListener : (String) -> ()

    init(l : @escaping (String) -> ())
    {
        self.mOnNetworkListener = l

    }
}

let mNetworkConnectionManager = NetworkConnectionManager { (packet) in
    var bp : BASPacket = BASPacket(packet: packet)
    bp.setTimestampedPacket(timestampPacket(packet, sentrec: "sent"));

    mOnBASMessageListener.onBASMessageSent(bp);
}
```